# Finding the universal cover of a matrix group

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups

Consider the group $G = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}: a \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}, b \in \mathbb{C}\right\} \subset GL(2, \mathbb{C})$. How does one find the universal cover of this group? In general, if I had a larger explicit matrix, what would I do?

Comment: I changed the tags to two that I thought were most specific -- feel free to revert. Interesting question!

Comment: Do you know how to find the universal cover of $G$ as a topological space, and how to write down the covering map? From there it suffices to figure out how to lift the group structure.

Comment: Er, no actually, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @109230: okay. Do you know how to find the universal cover of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$?